# Show that the mapping $B\rightarrow I_{B}:P(A)\rightarrow 2^{A}$ is a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this question from textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling at page 23. This exercise assumes only Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms of set, except for axiom of choice (which is presented in the next section). After some hours thinking, I still have no idea how to approach this exercise. Please shed some light on this problem. Many thanks!

Let $Z^{+}$ be the minimal infinite successor set. Consider the two-point subset $\{0,1\}$ of $Z^{+}$. We denote the set of functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$ by $2^{A}$. Suppose that $B\in P(A)$ and $x\in A$. Let $I_{B}(x)=1$ if $x\in B$, and $I_{B}(x)=0$ if $x\notin B$. $I_{B}$ is the *indicator function* of $B$. Show that the mapping $B\rightarrow I_{B}:P(A)\rightarrow 2^{A}$ is a bijection.

[image: Snapshot from textbook]

Comment: To prove injectivity show that $B\neq C\implies 1_B\neq1_C$ to prove surjectivity prove that for every function $f:A\to\{0,1\}$ there is a set $B\subseteq A$ such that $f=1_B$.

Comment: Hi @drhab, I don't understand why the author name the mapping $B\rightarrow I_{B}$, while the codomain is $2^{A}$?

Comment: If $f$ denotes the mapping then formally $f:\wp(A)\to2^A$ is a function prescribed by $B\mapsto1_B$. In the prescription $B$ is a variable element of domain $\wp(A)$ (so is a subset of $A$) and $1_B$ is an element of codomain $2^A$.

Comment: $1_B$ takes one of two values $\{0,1\}$ but $2^A =$ Funct$(A,\{0,1\})$. How can $1_B$ be an element of $2^A$?

Comment: $1_B$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $2=\{0,1\}$ (hence is an element of $2^A$). It is prescribed by $a\mapsto1$ if $a\in B$ and $a\mapsto0$ otherwise. Here $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: Your confusion might find its roots in the part in your title that says: "the mapping $B\to1_B$...". It should be "the mapping $\wp(A)\to2^A$ that is prescribed by $B\mapsto1_B$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are dealing here with a function $f:\wp(A)\to 2^A$ that is prescribed by $B\mapsto 1_B$.

In words: the function sends every element $B$ of $\wp(A)$ to the indicator function $1_B$ which on its turn is a function that has $A$ as domain and has $\{0,1\}$ as codomain.

Every $g\in 2^A$ induces a set $B_g:=\{a\in A\mid g(a)=1\}$ and it is not hard to show that: $$f(B_g)=1_{B_g}=g$$Proved is now that $f$ is surjective.

If $B,C\subseteq A$ with $B\neq C$ then $B-C\neq\varnothing$ or $C-B\neq\varnothing$.

Suppose that $B-C\neq\varnothing$ and let it be that $a\in B-C$.

Then $1_B(a)=1\neq0=1_C(a)$ so that $1_B\neq 1_C$.

Likewise it can be proved that $1_B\neq 1_C$ if $C-B\neq\varnothing$.

Proved is now: $$B\neq C\implies f(B)=1_B\neq1_C=f(C)$$which means exactly that $f$ is injective.

So $f$ is bijective and we are ready.

Comment: Many thanks @drhab! I got it.

Comment: You are very welcome

Comment: Hi @drhab, I have a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613220/possible-typos-in-the-proof-of-recursion-theorem, but I'm not satisfied with the answer. Can you have a look at my comment in that post and shed me some light?